# Как десериализовать JSON объекты хранимые в файле большого размера?

Tags: c#, json

Если файл хранящий JSON объекты достаточно большой, его десериализация в массив/список объектов может привести к ошибке OutOfMemory.

Как при помощи DataContractJsonSerializer можно реализовать последовательное считывание и десериализацию объектов из файла, не десериализуя весь файл сразу в массив объектов.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39967513/6808809